# How to delete values of the upper 10% quantile

Tags: r, quantile, non-linear-regression

Having following data (taken from: https://www.r-bloggers.com/first-steps-with-non-linear-regression-in-r/):

```
#simulate some data
set.seed(20160227)
x<-seq(0,50,1)
y<-((runif(1,10,20)*x)/(runif(1,0,10)+x))+rnorm(51,0,1)
#for simple models nls find good starting values for the parameters even if it throw a warning
m<-nls(y~a*x/(b+x))
#get some estimation of goodness of fit
cor(y,predict(m))

[1] 0.9496598

#plot
plot(x,y)
lines(x,predict(m),lty=2,col="red",lwd=3)
```

[image]

How to remove values representing the upper 10% quantile of the ratio of y ~ x?

With the following code a line representing the 90% quantile can be drawn. What I´m missing is how to remove all data (y~x) which are located above the 90% quantile (green line)

```
# prepare data
xy <- as.data.table(cbind(x,y)) 
xy <- xy[-1, ]

# fit line 
fit.nlrq.09 <-  nlrq(y ~ SSmicmen(x, Vm, K), data = xy, tau = 0.90) 
lines(fitted(fit.nlrq.09) ~ x, xy, col=3)
```

[image]

Comment: By data you mean: `x`, `y` or `m`?

Comment: Whichever variable you want, the simplest filtering of a vector seems to be `z <- z[ z < quantile(z,0.9) ]`. If you want to remove rows of a `data.frame` or remove the indices of all variables based on one's percentile, then `ind <- (z<quantile(z,0.9)) ; df[ind,] ; vec <- vec[ind]; ...`.